# Toggle button if checkbox is check

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a sign up form and i want to allow user to press the create account button only if he check the checkbox and if not the button is unclickable.The form looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="nume" value="" placeholder="Nume" /><br />
<input type="text" name="prenume" value="" placeholder="Prenume" /><br />
<input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" /><br />
<input type="password" name="password1" value="" placeholder="Parola" /><br />
<input type="email" name="email1" value="" placeholder="E-mail" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="reguli" id="reguli" required >     
<label for="reguli">I agree with the website rules</label><br />
<input type="submit" name="cont" value="Creare cont" />
```

Found what I search : [Toggle Button](http://jsfiddle.net/DQjZT/)

Comment: This is not really a question, more like a request for code. If you put effort into this and show it, we're more than willing to help you when you get stuck.

Comment: I am searching how to do this for almost 2 hours, i am 17 and i have to make a  website for my last highschool exams and im not very good with java this is why i try to find out how to do this...

Comment: @Filip, Write a code even if its just a wrong. Atleast show that you have tried but not able to do so. If you just ask for code no-one will help you

Comment: @Filip Java != JavaScript

Comment: On submit what do you want to do?

Comment: Create account for login

Comment: which platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give id to your button like

```
<input type="submit" name="cont" id="btnsubmit" disabled="true" value="Creare cont" />
```

Then add following code to your javascript and you are done

```
$("#reguli").change(function(){
    $("#btnsubmit").prop("disabled",!this.checked);
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ranjitsss/Dh79m/)

Comment: Big thank you, man! Im only 17 and i really try to learn but if no 1 helps me because they say i do not search only ask they mistake

Comment: @Filip Its my pleasure to help you man, its good you started coding only in 17, Try to involve your fellow friends on stackoverflow, Play with programs like game and one day you will be a good coder. All the very best.

Comment: I try to do my best, thank you for this code and for your encouragement words. Have a nice day.

Comment: can you please tell me what jquery library i have to put in  my php to make this code work i try jquery 2.1.0 but does not work

Comment: include 1.8.3.. but there is no reason for not running this script in 2.1.0.

Comment: i put the 1.8.3 script in head but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

use the jquery validate plugin
    $('#signup form').validate({
    rules: {
    reguli: {
    required: true,
    }}});

Comment: thank you too for trying to help me i appreciate very much